# Having a problem rendering a triangle in modern OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

I was expecting the program to render a simple triangle on top of a grey background but instead it renders
[a background but no triangle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9TDO.png)

My compiler shows no warnings or errors, neither does *SDL2* or *GLAD*. I have concluded that the cause of this behavior is contained within either of these two snippets of code. Just as a reference I am programming this in C, and using OpenGL 4.2.

within shader.h

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

// vertex shader
const char* vertexShaderSrc = 
    "#version 420 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}\0";

unsigned int vShader;



// fragment shader
const char* fragmentShaderSrc =
    "#version 420 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n\0";

unsigned int fShader;

// shader program
unsigned int sProgram;

#endif // SHADER_H
```

within main.c

```
    // SETUP TRIANGLE
    float triVertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    // vertex buffer object / vertex array object
    unsigned int vbo, vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    // vao
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // vbo
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triVertices), triVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);


    // vertex shader
    vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &vertexShaderSrc, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vShader);

    glGetShaderiv(vShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("vertex shader error: %s\n", infoLog);
        isRunning = false;
    }


    // fragment shader
    fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSrc, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fShader);

    glGetShaderiv(fShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("fragment shader error: %s\n", infoLog);
        isRunning = false;
    }


    // shader program
    sProgram = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(sProgram, vShader);
    glAttachShader(sProgram, fShader);
    glLinkProgram(sProgram);

    glGetProgramiv(sProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(sProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("shader program errror: %s\n", infoLog);
        isRunning = false;
    }

    glDeleteShader(vShader);
    glDeleteShader(fShader);



    // APPLICATION LOOP
    while(isRunning) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch(event.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    isRunning = false; 
                    break;
                default: 
                    break;
            }
        }

        // display
        glClearColor(0.15f, 0.15f, 0.15f, 1.0f);
        glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(sProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }
```

I have attempted to fix my problem by changing the order in which a number functions are placed, appointing different values to these functions, and modifying my shaders' source code. None of these actions seemed to work and so I have reverted my code to it's original state. I have looked back at my [reference](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/2.1.hello_triangle/hello_triangle.cpp) in order to see if I had missed anything, but I wasn't able to track anything down.

Comment: I feel you bro, I had the same problem. At least one hour to get what i was doing wrong. I dont think anyone will sit to read the 100 lines of code to see what are you doing wrong. I will recomend you instead this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBbPWSOQ0-w&feature=youtu.be) if you want to keep using the same openGl version as the tutorial. Or if you want an easyer way, I would recomend you looking into `glDebugMessageCallback`.

Comment: That book teaches you how to debug a program until chapter 47. I think that should be the first thing you should learn. So you can take a look into that links. We are learning this together man, [this is my result if it helps you to compare](https://github.com/Polo123456789/OpenGL/blob/main/src/primer_triangulo.cpp). I just did it last week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your triangle's vertices have the same Y coordinate

```
float triVertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f
};
```

should be

```
float triVertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.0f, +0.5f, 0.0f    // here I have changed -0.5 to +0.5
};
```

Small update:  I have looked at the reference after posting this and this confirms my guess. The triangle has the same Y value for the third vertex.

The rest of the program seems fine, as long as SDL and OpenGL's shader compiler does not produce any warnings.

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess i was right when i said i was an idiot when it comes to this... i cannot believe i made you go through all this code in order for me to figure out that it was just a problem with my vertices, im so sorry! Nonetheless, you are a hero.

Comment: I had just two guesses: depth buffer setup (but it was OK) and typos in data. I also have a big "track record" of similar errors found by my colleagues )  Another common source of errors in OpenGL when "everything is black" is the blending mode setup and erros in matrices.